# GitLab Authentication header?

Tags: php, git, authentication, gitlab

Is there any known way to access private repositories trough PHP using headers of any kind or any library to handle this?

I'm thinking of a way to download the ZIP file of the master repository using only CURL inside PHP directly to the server then perform some action on the zip...

Comment: There are a few different options. Can you tell us more about your use case? Do you need users to permit you to access _their_ private repositories?

Comment: @Chris it's only for personal repositories I host at gitlab.com, I need to be able to fetch the code from gitlab and implement it into a production environment (will be used for classes and a custom mvc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not 100% clear on the details of what you're trying to do, but you should be able to download an archive of your repository using [GitLab's "Get file archive" API endpoint](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/repositories.html#get-file-archive) using [either a private token or a personal authentication token for authentication](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/#authentication).

Both of these token types may be specified using a `PRIVATE-TOKEN` HTTP header.